# Work out Linear System Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the linear system
$$
2x_i-6\alpha x_2 = 3, $$ $$
3\alpha x_1-x_2 = \frac{3}{2} 
$$
(a) Find the value of $\alpha$ for which has no solutions 
(b) Find the value of $\alpha$ for which has an infinite number of solutions 
(c) Find the unique solution a given $\alpha$

I have the answers for these questions (solutions manual) but I'm having a hard time with what happens in the middle.

Comment: Can you tell what you have actually tried as it will help us to provide better direction? Do you have ideas of how to approach it? What are you currently studying (RREF, Gaussian Elimination, Determinants ...) so we can answer along those line? Regards

Comment: We've covered all those things. I've reduced the matrix down to $$
\left[\begin{matrix} 
 2 & -6\alpha    & 3  \\
 0 & (3\alpha-1)(3\alpha+1) & \frac{3(1-3\alpha)}{2} 
\end{matrix}\right]
$$ which helped me get the unique solution but i'm not sure about a and b

Answer (score 1):

Just a few general tips:

For (a) and (b) you need to determine when the matrix becomes singular. Remember which equality needs to be satisfied for a matrix to be singular and then solve it for $\alpha$.

If the matrix is singular, the given linear equation may have infinitely many solutions or no solution at all. Infinitely many if the right hand side is in the range of the matrix, no solution otherwise. It shouldn't prove too difficult to figure out the range of the matrix in each case, since it's just a one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

For (c) assuming the matrix is non-singular, use e.g. Gaussian elimination. For $2\times2$ matrices there is also direct formula that gives you the inverse. Or use Cramer's rule, which is also feasible if the linear system is as small as this one.